# React.js - input losing focus when rerendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am just writing to text input and in `onChange` event I call `setState`, so React re-renders my UI. The problem is that the text input always loses focus, so I need to focus it again for each letter :D.

```
var EditorContainer = React.createClass({

    componentDidMount: function () {
        $(this.getDOMNode()).slimScroll({height: this.props.height, distance: '4px', size: '8px'});
    },

    componentDidUpdate: function () {
        console.log("zde");
        $(this.getDOMNode()).slimScroll({destroy: true}).slimScroll({height: 'auto', distance: '4px', size: '8px'});
    },

    changeSelectedComponentName: function (e) {
        //this.props.editor.selectedComponent.name = $(e.target).val();
        this.props.editor.forceUpdate();
    },

    render: function () {

        var style = {
            height: this.props.height + 'px'
        };
        return (
            <div className="container" style={style}>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-xs-6">
                    {this.props.selected ? <h3>{this.props.selected.name}</h3> : ''}
                    {this.props.selected ? <input type="text" value={this.props.selected.name} onChange={this.changeSelectedComponentName} /> : ''}
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-xs-6">
                        <ComponentTree editor={this.props.editor} components={this.props.components}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }

});
```

Comment: The only reason that'd happen is if a) something else steals focus, or b) the input is flickering.  Could you provided a jsfiddle/jsbin showing the problem?  Here's a [base react jsbin](http://jsbin.com/fexoyoqi/1/edit).

Comment: lol... well that sounds a bit annoying :P
With jquery I would set an identifier for the new rendered inputfiled and then call focus on it. Not sure how the code would look in plain js. But I'm sure you can do it :)

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand: what do you mean by flickering?

Comment: @Krab, like if this.props.selected was becoming false, and then becoming true again.  That'd cause the input to unmount, and then mount again.

Comment: @Krab, try removing the slimScroll lines; that could be doing something weird that's causing problems.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand: you are right, ty. That slimScroll in componentDidUpdate causes this problem. But i thought react is just comparing outputs from subsequent render calls. That slimScroll doesn't modify output from render function.

Comment: @Krab, no but it probably messes with the DOM; so when React goes to make changes; there's something different there than what it expects.  This causes problems.

Comment: I have answered this question on one other post. Sharing the link below
[https://stackoverflow.com/a/70750600/5996276](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70750600/5996276)

Answer (score 144):

Without seeing the rest of your code, this is a guess.
When you create a EditorContainer, specify a unique key for the component:

`<EditorContainer key="editor1"/>`

When a re-rendering occurs, if the same key is seen, this will tell React don't clobber and regenerate the view, instead reuse. Then the focused item should retain focus.

Comment: This solved my problem with rendering a sub-component containing an input form. But in my case I needed the opposite -- the form was not re-rendering when I wanted it to. Adding the key attribute worked.

Comment: adding key to the input did not help

Comment: Maybe component(s) that contain your input also re-rendered. Check keys on enclosing components.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Such a problem is often due to keys. I had the same problem. Moreover, I accidentally accidentally put it in general key={Math.random()}

Answer (score 112):

I keep coming back here again and again and always find the solution to my elsewhere at the end.
So, I'll document it here because I know I will forget this again!

The reason `input` was losing focus in my case was due to the fact that I was re-rendering the `input` on state change.

### Buggy Code:

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

class SuperAwesomeComp extends React.Component {
  state = {
    email: ''
  };
  updateEmail = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ email: e.target.value });
  };
  render() {
    const Container = styled.div``;
    const Input = styled.input``;
    return (
      <Container>
        <Input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Gimme your email!"
          onChange={this.updateEmail}
          value={this.state.email}
        />
      </Container>
    )
  }
}
```

So, the problem is that I always start coding everything at one place to quickly test and later break it all into separate modules.
But, here this strategy backfires because updating the state on input change triggers render function and the focus is lost.

Fix is simple, do the modularization from the beginning, in other words, "Move the `Input` component out of `render` function"

### Fixed Code

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Container = styled.div``;
const Input = styled.input``;

class SuperAwesomeComp extends React.Component {
  state = {
    email: ''
  };
  updateEmail = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ email: e.target.value });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Gimme your email!"
          onChange={this.updateEmail}
          value={this.state.email}
        />
      </Container>
    )
  }
}
```

Ref. to the solution: https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/540#issuecomment-283664947

Comment: I was using a HOC inside the render function, moving the HOC call to the component definition did the trick. Somehow similar to this answer.

Comment: I think this is my problem, but I am having trouble moving the Components outside of `render()` and the `class ... extends Component` because of the reference to `this`. e.g. `onChange={this.handleInputChange}`

Comment: @Nateous Can you pass the function to the component as a prop?  Or do I misunderstand your issue?

Comment: @Abe I probably could, but been out of this for a bit. Still using react, but I paid for a course and am getting a bit further along now.

Comment: The morale of the story, for React class components, don't define components inside the `render` function, for React functional components, don't define components in the function body.

Comment: @Wong Jia Hau: What happens when you define components in the function body for React functional components? 
I also had a similar issue and it got fixed by applying your suggestion.

Comment: @Nateous I had exactly the same situation. HOC calls inside the `render` function that were being passed the 'this.handleChange' method and returned the components to be used. E.g. `const TextAreaDataField = TextAreaDataFieldFactory(this.handleChange)`. I simply moved the component creation to the constructor and access them in the `render` method as `this.TextAreaDataField`. Worked like a charm.

Comment: Similar issue with my component and it was all due to the "'styled-components'" being inside the render function so it would render a new styledComponent. Thanks for giving me the hint!

Comment: for functional components just move the styled.input out of functional component's definition

Comment: Thank you! I had my styled-components defined inside a functional component. Once I moved them out this fixed the issue

Answer (score 55):

I had the same symptoms with hooks. Yet my problem was defining a component inside the parent.

Wrong:

```
const Parent =() => {
    const Child = () => <p>Child!</p>
    return <Child />
}
```

Right:

```
const Child = () => <p>Child!</p>
const Parent = () => <Child />
```

Comment: `const child` should be `const Child`, in the 'Wrong' example.

Comment: Note that you could still use such a nested child via a regular function call. For instance, `return <div>{Child()}</div>` would be okay, although admittedly a bit ugly. I sometimes find it helpful to pull out non-reusable parts of the JSX expression into local closures for readability, without having to make them full stand-alone components with lots of props passing. The focus behavior is a bit of a gotcha.

Comment: It **mounts** the child every time the parent re-renders

Comment: Just to expand what @ilkerkaran said, because React will run your component function (the `Parent` function) on every state update, the value of `Child` inside will be different for every render. Thus, React cannot reuse your the child component in each render, and you will end up with new elements for every update.

Answer (score 48):

If it's a problem within a react router `<Route/>` use the `render` prop instead of `component`.

```
<Route path="/user" render={() => <UserPage/>} />
```

The loss of focus happens because the `component` prop uses `React.createElement` each time instead of just re-rendering the changes.

Details here: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/component

Comment: This was essentially my issue. Specifically, I was passing an anonymous function to the component prop, triggering focus-loss: `<Route component={() => <MyComponent/>} />`, when I should've done `<Route component={MyComponent} />`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/47660885/11667949. In my case this helped

Answer (score 22):

My answer is similar to what @z5h said.

In my case, I used `Math.random()` to generate a unique `key` for the component.

I thought the `key` is only used for triggering a rerender for that particular component rather than re-rendering all the components in that array (I return an array of components in my code). I didn't know it is used for restoring the state after rerendering.

Removing that did the job for me.

Comment: A module like https://www.npmjs.com/package/shortid is also a nice way to handle something like this.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/47660885/11667949. In my case this helped

Comment: Thanks. This was also my issue. I was using `key={index+Date.now()}`. Because that changes, the component didn't preserve its state. Switching to `key={index}` solved it for me.

Answer (score 18):

What I did was just change the `value` prop to `defaultValue` and second change was `onChange` event to `onBlur`.

Comment: OnBlur resolved my problem, thanks

Comment: Thank you so much! I was incredibly frustrated with this issue for two whole days. I tried adding the key and everything else I could think of, but nothing seemed to work.

Answer (score 11):

Applying the `autoFocus` attribute to the `input` element can perform as a workaround in situations where there's only one input that needs to be focused. In that case a `key` attribute would be unnecessary because it's just one element and furthermore you wouldn't have to worry about breaking the `input` element into its own component to avoid losing focus on re-render of main component.

Comment: Had to try this as last-resort workaround. I'm glad it works. There's obviously a bug in my app as the app re-renders whenever I try to type in the only search input in page. But getting `autofocus` to the input field is a start. 

Comment: This worked for me too, after trying many many other solutions.   It still re-renders which isn't great but it is functional.  TY!

Comment: keep in mind if you use this with multiple inputs it will introduce other issues. Ex: typing in one field which loses focus will automatically move the user to the input field with autoFocus enabled.

Comment: This seems like an even worse bug tbh, almost certainly you'll forget you took this workaround if/when there's another input added to page later. It's not a solution, it's just changing the presentation of the bug.

Answer (score 6):

I got the same behavior.

The problem in my code was that i created a nested Array of jsx elements like this:

```
const example = [
            [
                <input value={'Test 1'}/>,
                <div>Test 2</div>,
                <div>Test 3</div>,
            ]
        ]

...

render = () => {
    return <div>{ example }</div>
}
```

Every element in this nested Array re-renders each time I updated the parent element. And so the inputs lose there "ref" prop every time

I fixed the Problem with transform the inner array to a react component
(a function with a render function)

```
const example = [
            <myComponentArray />
        ]

 ...

render = () => {
    return <div>{ example }</div>
}
```

**EDIT:**

The same issue appears when i build a nested `React.Fragment`

```
const SomeComponent = (props) => (
    <React.Fragment>
        <label ... />
        <input ... />
    </React.Fragment>
);

const ParentComponent = (props) => (
    <React.Fragment>
        <SomeComponent ... />
        <div />
    </React.Fragment>
);
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/47660885/11667949. In my case this helped

Answer (score 5):

I solved the same issue deleting the key attribute in the input and his parent elements

```js
// Before
<input
    className='invoice_table-input invoice_table-input-sm'
    type='number'
    key={ Math.random }
    defaultValue={pageIndex + 1}
    onChange={e => {
        const page = e.target.value ? Number(e.target.value) - 1 : 0
        gotoPage(page)
    }}
/>
// After
<input
    className='invoice_table-input invoice_table-input-sm'
    type='number'
    defaultValue={pageIndex + 1}
    onChange={e => {
        const page = e.target.value ? Number(e.target.value) - 1 : 0
        gotoPage(page)
    }}
/>
```

Comment: True, in my case, i deleted the key and it worked perfect. I was mapping multiple textInputs

Comment: It should be noted that Math.random as a key is a react anti-pattern. The whole point of a key is to tell React, "This is my component, you can find it by this key. Rerender THIS component when needed" Having a new random key doesn't let React keep track of it.

Answer (score 4):

The answers supplied didn't help me, here was what I did but I had a unique situation.

To clean up the code I tend to use this format until I'm ready to pull the component into another file.

```
render(){
   const MyInput = () => {
      return <input onChange={(e)=>this.setState({text: e.target.value}) />
   }
   return(
      <div>
         <MyInput />
      </div>
   )
```

But this caused it to lose focus, when I put the code directly in the div it worked.

```
return(
   <div>
      <input onChange={(e)=>this.setState({text: e.target.value}) />
   </div>
)
```

I don't know why this is, this is the only issue I've had with writing it this way and I do it in most files I have, but if anyone does a similar thing this is why it loses focus.

Answer (score 4):

If the input field is inside another element (i.e., a container element like `<div key={"bart"}...><input key={"lisa"}...> ... </input></div>`-- the ellipses here indicating omitted code), **there must be a unique and constant key on the container element (as well as on the input field)**.  Elsewise, React renders up a brand new container element when child's state is updated rather than merely re-rendering the old container.  Logically, only the child element should be updated, but...

I had this problem while trying to write a component that took a bunch of address information.  The working code looks like this

```js
// import react, components
import React, { Component } from 'react'

// import various functions
import uuid from "uuid";

// import styles
import "../styles/signUp.css";

export default class Address extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      address1: "",
      address2: "",
      address1Key: uuid.v4(),
      address2Key: uuid.v4(),
      address1HolderKey: uuid.v4(),
      address2HolderKey: uuid.v4(),
      // omitting state information for additional address fields for brevity
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ [`${event.target.id}`]: event.target.value })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <fieldset>
        <div className="labelAndField" key={this.state.address1HolderKey} >
          <label className="labelStyle" for="address1">{"Address"}</label>
          <input className="inputStyle"
            id="address1"
            name="address1"
            type="text"
            label="address1"
            placeholder=""
            value={this.state.address1}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            key={this.state.address1Key} ></input >
        </div> 
        <div className="labelAndField" key={this.state.address2HolderKey} >
          <label className="labelStyle" for="address2">{"Address (Cont.)"}</label>
          <input className="inputStyle"
            id="address2"
            name="address2"
            type="text"
            label="address2"
            placeholder=""
            key={this.state.address2Key} ></input >
        </div>
        {/* omitting rest of address fields for brevity */}
      </fieldset>
    )
  }
}
```

Sharp-eyed readers will note that `<fieldset>` is a containing element, yet it doesn't require a key.  The same holds for `<>` and `<React.Fragment>` or even `<div>` Why?  Maybe only the immediate container needs a key.  I dunno.  As math textbooks say, the explanation is left to the reader as an exercise.

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue and the problem turned out to be that I was using a functional component and linking up with a parent component's state. If I switched to using a class component, the problem went away. Hopefully there is a way around this when using functional components as it's a lot more convenient for simple item renderers et al.

Answer (score 3):

included the next code in tag input:

```
ref={(input) => {
     if (input) {
         input.focus();
     }
 }}
```

Before:

```
<input
      defaultValue={email}
      className="form-control"
      type="email"
      id="email"
      name="email"
      placeholder={"mail@mail.com"}
      maxLength="15"
      onChange={(e) => validEmail(e.target.value)}
/>
```

After:

```
<input
     ref={(input) => {
          if (input) {
             input.focus();
          }
      }}
      defaultValue={email}
      className="form-control"
      type="email"
      id="email"
      name="email"
      placeholder={"mail@mail.com"}
      maxLength="15"
      onChange={(e) => validEmail(e.target.value)}
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this issue and came here for help. Check your CSS! The input field cannot have `user-select: none;` or it won't work on an iPad.

Answer (score 2):

For me, this was being caused by the search input box being rendered in the **same** component (called UserList) as the list of search results. So whenever the search results changed, the whole UserList component rerendered, including the input box.

My solution was to create a whole new component called **UserListSearch** which is separate from **UserList**. I did not need to set keys on the input fields in UserListSearch for this to work. The render function of my UsersContainer now looks like this:

```
class UserContainer extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Route
          exact
          path={this.props.match.url}
          render={() => (
            <div>
              <UserListSearch
                handleSearchChange={this.handleSearchChange}
                searchTerm={this.state.searchTerm}
              />
              <UserList
                isLoading={this.state.isLoading}
                users={this.props.users}
                user={this.state.user}
                handleNewUserClick={this.handleNewUserClick}
              />
            </div>
          )}
        />
      </div>  
    )
  }
}
```

Hopefully this helps someone too.

Answer (score 2):

I switched `value` prop to `defaultValue`. That works for me.

```
...
// before
<input value={myVar} />

// after
<input defaultValue={myVar} />
```

Answer (score 2):

My problem was that I named my key dynamically with a value of the item, in my case "name" so the key was key={`${item.name}-${index}`}. So when I wanted to change the input with item.name as the value, they key would also change and therefore react would not recognize that element

Answer (score 2):

For me I had a text area inside a portal. This text area was loosing focus. My buggy portal implementation was like this:

```
export const Modal = ({children, onClose}: modelProps) => {
  const modalDOM = document.getElementById("modal");
  const divRef = useRef(document.createElement('div')); 

  useEffect(()=>{
    const ref = divRef.current;
    modalDOM?.appendChild(ref);
    return ()=>{
      modalDOM?.removeChild(ref);
    }
  });

  const close = (e: React.MouseEvent) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    onClose();
  };

  const handleClick = (e: React.MouseEvent) => {
    e.stopPropagation()
  }

  return (
    createPortal(
    <div className="modal" onClick={close}>
      <div className="modal__close-modal" onClick={close}>x</div>
      {children}
    </div>, 
    divRef.current)
  )
}

const Parent = ({content: string}: ParentProps) => {
  const [content, setContent] = useState<string>(content);
  
  const onChangeFile = (e: React.MouseEvent) => {
    setContent(e.currentTarget.value);
  }

  return (
    <Modal>
      <textarea
        value={content}
        onChange={onChangeFile}>
      </textarea>
    </Modal>
    )
  }
```

Turned out following implementation worked correctly, here I am directly attaching modal component to the DOM element.

```
export const Modal = ({children, onClose}: modelProps) => {
  const modalDOM = document.getElementById("modal");

  const close = (e: React.MouseEvent) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    onClose();
  };

  return (
    createPortal(
      <div className="modal" onClick={close}>
        <div className="modal__close-modal" onClick={close}>x</div>
          {children}
        </div>, 
        modalDOM || document.body)
    )
  }
```

Comment: I see that you removed your `useEffect`. My issue was similar, found out that my `useEffect` was missing its dependencies. By adding it `useEffect(() => , [])`, it solved the issue

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue, this is fixed it.

```
const component = () => {
 return <input onChange={({target})=>{
    setValue(target.vlaue)
   }       
 } />
}

const ThisComponentKeptRefreshingContainer = () => {
   return(
     <component />
   )
}

const ThisContainerDidNot= () => {
   return(
     <> {component()} </>
   )
}
```

As the code illustrate calling the component child like an element gave that re-rendering effect, however, calling it like a function did not.
hope it helps someone

Comment: I found the same thing! This was the easiest fix for me, using a custom hook which returns (along the lines of): `{component: (props) => <><otherstuff/><input {...props}/></>, ...helperMethods}`. Would love to know why this works so I can switch back to using the component directly.

Answer (score 1):

The core reason is: When React re-render, your previous DOM ref will be invalid. It mean react has change the DOM tree, and you this.refs.input.focus won't work, because the input here doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: So what is your solution?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with an html table in which I have input text lines in a column. inside a loop I read a json object and I create rows in particular I have a column with inputtext.

http://reactkungfu.com/2015/09/react-js-loses-input-focus-on-typing/

I managed to solve it in the following way

```
import { InputTextComponent } from './InputTextComponent';
//import my  inputTextComponent 
...

var trElementList = (function (list, tableComponent) {

    var trList = [],
        trElement = undefined,
        trElementCreator = trElementCreator,
        employeeElement = undefined;



    // iterating through employee list and
    // creating row for each employee
    for (var x = 0; x < list.length; x++) {

        employeeElement = list[x];

        var trNomeImpatto = React.createElement('tr', null, <td rowSpan="4"><strong>{employeeElement['NomeTipologiaImpatto'].toUpperCase()}</strong></td>);
        trList.push(trNomeImpatto);

        trList.push(trElementCreator(employeeElement, 0, x));
        trList.push(trElementCreator(employeeElement, 1, x));
        trList.push(trElementCreator(employeeElement, 2, x));

    } // end of for  

    return trList; // returns row list

    function trElementCreator(obj, field, index) {
        var tdList = [],
            tdElement = undefined;

        //my input text
        var inputTextarea = <InputTextComponent
            idImpatto={obj['TipologiaImpattoId']}//index
            value={obj[columns[field].nota]}//initial value of the input I read from my json data source
            noteType={columns[field].nota}
            impattiComposite={tableComponent.state.impattiComposite}
            //updateImpactCompositeNote={tableComponent.updateImpactCompositeNote}
        />

        tdElement = React.createElement('td', { style: null }, inputTextarea);
        tdList.push(tdElement);


        var trComponent = createClass({

            render: function () {
                return React.createElement('tr', null, tdList);
            }
        });
        return React.createElement(trComponent);
    } // end of trElementCreator

});
...    
    //my tableComponent
    var tableComponent = createClass({
        // initial component states will be here
        // initialize values
        getInitialState: function () {
            return {
                impattiComposite: [],
                serviceId: window.sessionStorage.getItem('serviceId'),
                serviceName: window.sessionStorage.getItem('serviceName'),
                form_data: [],
                successCreation: null,
            };
        },

        //read a json data soure of the web api url
        componentDidMount: function () {
            this.serverRequest =
                $.ajax({
                    url: Url,
                    type: 'GET',
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    data: JSON.stringify({ id: this.state.serviceId }),
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (response) {
                        this.setState({ impattiComposite: response.data });
                    }.bind(this),

                    error: function (xhr, resp, text) {
                        // show error to console
                        console.error('Error', xhr, resp, text)
                        alert(xhr, resp, text);
                    }
                });
        },

        render: function () {
    ...
    React.createElement('table', {style:null}, React.createElement('tbody', null,trElementList(this.state.impattiComposite, this),))
    ...
    }



            //my input text
            var inputTextarea = <InputTextComponent
                        idImpatto={obj['TipologiaImpattoId']}//index
                        value={obj[columns[field].nota]}//initial value of the input I read //from my json data source
                        noteType={columns[field].nota}
                        impattiComposite={tableComponent.state.impattiComposite}//impattiComposite  = my json data source

                    />//end my input text

                    tdElement = React.createElement('td', { style: null }, inputTextarea);
                    tdList.push(tdElement);//add a component

        //./InputTextComponent.js
        import React from 'react';

        export class InputTextComponent extends React.Component {
          constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
              idImpatto: props.idImpatto,
              value: props.value,
              noteType: props.noteType,
              _impattiComposite: props.impattiComposite,
            };
            this.updateNote = this.updateNote.bind(this);
          }

        //Update a inpute text with new value insert of the user

          updateNote(event) {
            this.setState({ value: event.target.value });//update a state of the local componet inputText
            var impattiComposite = this.state._impattiComposite;
            var index = this.state.idImpatto - 1;
            var impatto = impattiComposite[index];
            impatto[this.state.noteType] = event.target.value;
            this.setState({ _impattiComposite: impattiComposite });//update of the state of the father component (tableComponet)

          }

          render() {
            return (
              <input
                className="Form-input"
                type='text'
                value={this.state.value}
                onChange={this.updateNote}>
              </input>
            );
          }
        }
```

Comment: Please use minimal code for answers - here we have a lot of unrelated code.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution in my case:

```
<input ref={ref => ref && ref.focus()}
    onFocus={(e)=>e.currentTarget.setSelectionRange(e.currentTarget.value.length, e.currentTarget.value.length)}
    />
```

`ref` triggers focus, and that triggers `onFocus` to calculate the end and set the cursor accordingly.

Comment: I am getting `Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?`

Comment: @VitalyZdanevich if you pass me a CodeSandbox I'm happy to debug

Comment: Just looks this `ref` is only for class component, not for a new function component.

Comment: I put this on an `<input />` in a functional component and it worked. Do you have an example of a functional component where this wasn't working?

Answer (score 1):

The issue in my case was that the key prop values I was setting on the InputContainer component and the input fields themselves were generated using Math.random(). The non-constant nature of the values made it hard for track to be kept of the input field being edited.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was binding `this` to the component which was causing it to rerender.

I figured I'd post it here in case anyone else had this issue.

I had to change

```
<Field
    label="Post Content"
    name="text"
    component={this.renderField.bind(this)}
/>
```

To

```
<Field
    label="Post Content"
    name="text"
    component={this.renderField}
/>
```

Simple fix since in my case, I didn't actually need `this` in `renderField`, but hopefully me posting this will help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

### With react-native

For me the issue was using `styled-components/native`.
After switching to the usual `StyleSheet` for the input component and its parents everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was the wrong use of react keys in the `.map()` function.

Keys must not depend on the input value. Otherwise, every time you change the value, react thinks it's a new input because the key has changed.

Answer (score 0):

In your React component, the issue you're encountering likely stems from the fact that you're manually calling forceUpdate() in the changeSelectedComponentName function. This causes the component to re-render, which in turn causes the input to lose focus.

To resolve this issue, you should avoid using forceUpdate() as much as possible, as it bypasses the normal React component lifecycle and can lead to unpredictable behavior.

Instead, you should update the component's state using setState() to trigger a re-render in a more controlled manner. Here's how you can refactor your component to address the issue:

```
var EditorContainer = React.createClass({

componentDidMount: function () {
    $(this.getDOMNode()).slimScroll({height: this.props.height, distance: '4px', size: '8px'});
},

componentDidUpdate: function () {
    console.log("zde");
    $(this.getDOMNode()).slimScroll({destroy: true}).slimScroll({height: 'auto', distance: '4px', size: '8px'});
},

changeSelectedComponentName: function (e) {
    var newName = e.target.value;
    // Update the selected component's name in the parent component's state
    this.props.editor.setSelectedComponentName(newName);
},

render: function () {
    var style = {
        height: this.props.height + 'px'
    };
    return (
        <div className="container" style={style}>
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-xs-6">
                {this.props.selected ? <h3>{this.props.selected.name}</h3> : ''}
                {this.props.selected ? <input type="text" value={this.props.selected.name} onChange={this.changeSelectedComponentName} /> : ''}
                </div>
                <div className="col-xs-6">
                    <ComponentTree editor={this.props.editor} components={this.props.components}/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

});

Answer (score -1):

Changing text in the input of some control can cause parent control rerendering in some cases (according to binding to props).
In this case focus will be lost. Editing should not has effect to parent container in DOM.