# React - input loses focus on keypress

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input

I have run into a weird bug with my search input component where it loses focus on every keypress and can't figure out why.

```
const App = () => {
  let [characters, setCharacters] = useState([]);
  let [filteredCharacters, setFilteredCharacters] = useState([]);
  // more state
  let [search, setSearch] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    axios
      .get(`https://swapi.co/api/people/?page=${pageNumber}`)
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data.results);
        setCharacters(res.data.results);
        setFilteredCharacters(res.data.results);
      })
      .catch(err => console.error(err))
      .then(() => {
        setIsLoading(false);
      });
  }, [pageNumber]);

  function updatePage(e) {
     // update page
  }

  function handleSearch(e) {
    setSearch(e.target.value);
    const filtered = characters.filter(character => {
      if (character.name.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(e.target.value) !== -1) {
        return character;
      }
    });
    setFilteredCharacters(filtered);
  }
  function SearchBar() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <StyledInput
          type="text"
          id="search"
          value={search}
          placeholder="Search by name..."
          onChange={e => handleSearch(e)}
        />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <GlobalStyles />
      <div className="App">
        <Heading>React Wars!</Heading>
        <SearchBar />
        <Pagination handleClick={updatePage} />
        {!isLoading && Object.entries(filteredCharacters).length ? (
          <CharacterList characters={filteredCharacters} />
        ) : (
          <LoadingBar />
        )}
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

I'm also getting a `Line 65:50:  Expected to return a value at the end of arrow function  array-callback-return` for the `characters.filter()` line so I don't know if that has to do with it.

If it helps, the deployed app with the bug can be seen here --> https://mundane-vacation.surge.sh

Comment: In React, if an input loses focus when a character is typed, 99% of the time it's because it's getting re-rendered. I'm guessing it's because you've nested functional components inside another and are using them as children. The `SearchBar`'s `onChange` calls `handleSearch`, which calls `setSearch`, which changes the state value and thus causes a re-render (including a re-render of the `SearchBar` child itself). Check out other questions like this one for ideas on how to fix: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42573017/in-react-es6-why-does-the-input-field-lose-focus-after-typing-a-character

Comment: you're defining `function SearchBar() {` every render, so it's a completely new component getting evaluated and rendered every time. You can omit that and inject the `StyledInput` contents in place of `<SearchBar />` and that should help

Comment: The warning/error you're getting is because your `characters` filter functor should be returning a boolean value every time, not the current value of the functor. You can simply return the value of that name tolowercase index check.

Comment: This helped me! Because it was more obvious:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59287017/7156690

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have a problem with focus because your component `SearchBar` is declared inside `App` component and it is recreated on each rendering. You need to move `SearchBar` out of `App` or just move `StyledInput` on the place of `SearchBar`. If you choose the first way, I recommend you remove `React.Fragment` from `SearchBar`, because it has only one rendered child:

```
function SearchBar(props) {
    return (
        <StyledInput
          type="text"
          id="search"
          value={props.value}
          placeholder="Search by name..."
          onChange={props.onChange}
        />
    );
  }
```

And in `App`:

```
<SearchBar onChange={handleSearch} value={search} />
```

To fix your warning, you need always return a boolean value inside the `filter` function. Now you return nothing (i.e. `undefined`) in case if the `character` does not pass the condition. So change your `filter` function like this:

```
const filtered = characters.filter(character => {
    return character.name.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(e.target.value) !== -1
});
```

Comment: Your answer helps me to solve my issue. Thanks.