# TextField lose focus when typing to Redux Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am using `MaterialUI` to build component `Expanded`, where inside I have list of text fields.

I store data in redux.

```
reduxState = {
    fieldName1:[
      {
          primaryText:"text1",
      },
      {
          primaryText:"text2"
      },
    ],
    fieldName2:[
      {
          primaryText:"text1"
      },
      {
          primaryText:"text2"
      },
    ]
}
```

Each `Exapanded` keeps a `textField` of each `fieldNameN`

the component `Exapanded` looks like this

```js
function Expanded(props) {
  const {onChange, title, list } = props

  const CustomPaper = withStyles({
     root:{
       color: blue
     }
  })(Paper)

  return (
    <ExpansionPanel>
      <ExpansionPanelSummary expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}>
        <Typography>{title}</Typography>
      </ExpansionPanelSummary>
      <ExpansionPanelDetails>
          <Grid container spacing={1} direction="row">
            {list.map((item,i) => 
              <CustomPaper key={i}>
                <TextInput label="Main Text" value={item.primaryText} xs={12} onChange={(value) => onChange(value, i, 'primaryText')}/>
              </CustomPaper >
            )} 
          </Grid>           
      </ExpansionPanelDetails>
    </ExpansionPanel>
  );
}
```

Example of use

```js
            <Expanded
              title={`Add FieldName1`}
              list={reduxState.fieldName1}
              onChange={onChangeSectionInfo('fieldName')}
            />
```

the `onChangeSelectionInfo` function calls redux action `updateSection` when typing

```js
    [formActionTypes.UPDATE_SECTION]: (state, action) => {
      //ex. field-FieldName, value-"text1Updated", index=0, element="primaryText"
      const { field, value, index, element } = action.payload;
     return {
        ...state,
        [field]: state[field].map((object, i) =>
          i === index ? { ...object, [element]: value } : object
        )
      };
    },
```

The problem is that I can only type one char, and then it unfocus the TextField. Is it the problem with redux, that it takes too long to update?

EDIT: The solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42573017/in-react-es6-why-does-the-input-field-lose-focus-after-typing-a-character) is not helping, I took out all the loops and still doesnt work

Comment: shouldn't you be passing the `onChangeSectionInfo` function itself instead of calling it in `onChange={onChangeSectionInfo('fieldName')}` ?

Comment: I use `Expanded` component inside other one which has defined function `onChangeSectionInfo`, that is why I send it as a props

Comment: but you don't send it as a props.  You send `onChangeSectionInfo('fieldName')` which is whatever that function returns.

Comment: I dont think it is a problem, since it is updating the value in redux once, and after then losing the focus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On every re-render you are re-creating the `CustomPaper` which will require a full remount of the component(CustomPaper) and not only a re-render, this is why you lose the focus.

Remove the component outside of your component and never define components inside components.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you type a character in the input the onChange is being called, which updates props, and your component is composed with props, so React re-renders it, which make the field lose focus.  Try changing the event handler to onBlur or something, if you can.

Current chain of events:

1. Use props to render component
2. Component renders input field
3. You type and onChange is triggered
4. Your onChange is passed up to the parent and props is updated
5. Props is used to render the component again.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was actually the `CustomPaper` in `Expanded` component that I created (I edited my question, before I didnt show that I was using `CustomPaper`, cause it didnt seem important to me). When I change `CustomPaper`to `Paper` from MaterialUI everything worked. Any ideas why?