# react-quill loses focus when onChange is called

Tags: reactjs, richtextbox, antd, quill, react-quill

I have a component wrapper in `antd` `Form.create()` HOC where I want to implement validation for my `react-quill` editor.

```
          <Form.Item>
            {getFieldDecorator('input', {
              rules: [RequiredRule],
              initialValue: text,
              onChange: this.onChangeText
            })(
              <ReactQuill
                className="question-form__rich-text"
                modules={quillToolbar}
              />,
            )}
          </Form.Item>
```

If I start typing inside my `quill` editor text field it triggers the `onChangeText` function which in its turn changes the local state and initiates rerender of the component

```
  onChangeText = (_, __, ___, editor) => {
    this.setState({
      textVal: editor.getText(),
    });
  };
```

```
 this.state = {
      textVal: '',
    };
```

Every time the component rerenders my text field loses focus, so I have to click inside the field to type another letter.
I noticed that it happens only if the `<ReactQuill>` component is wrapped by `antd` `<Form.Item>`

It also shows some weird behaviour if I put `console.log` inside `onChangeText` function and try to check what's inside the text field:
[image]

Let's say my text field is initially empty. I type letter 'a' and it calls the function 3 times. First, it shows that the text field contains letter 'a', then it calls the function again showing that the field is empty and then the 3rd time letter 'a' appears again. This behaviour persists as I keep typing.
Also, there is an warning saying `addRange(): The given range isn't in document.` which I have no idea what it means.

I've been struggling with that issue for a few days now, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: it is better to create/provide it on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/dashboard/home?workspace=4e7c51dd-157f-40a8-80ff-a651fe533cd6) or any other online ide for better debugging.

Comment: Here it is https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-booth-z9b5v?file=/src/richText.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it's loses focus when keypress is probably because the quill component is recreating when rerendering. See this same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42573017/in-react-es6-why-does-the-input-field-lose-focus-after-typing-a-character) about losing focus when typing.

I can't find a sample of implementing react quill on antd using `getFieldDecorator`, so I made a little workaround to make it work but same output. See this [working link](https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-wildflower-ztqdu?file=/src/richText.js:908-925) I made.

```
const { getFieldDecorator, validateFields, setFieldsValue } = props.form;

const onChangeText = (text) => {
  console.log("called");
  text = text !== "<p><br></p>" ? text : "";
  setFieldsValue({ input: text });
  setTextVal(text);
};


<Form.Item>
  {getFieldDecorator("input", {
    rules: [{ required: true }],
  })(<Input.TextArea style={{ display: "none" }} />)}
  <ReactQuill
    className="question-form__rich-text"
    modules={quillToolbar}
    defaultValue={textVal}
    onChange={onChangeText}
  />
</Form.Item>
```

as you can see in the above code, I place the editor outside `getFieldDecorator` and replaced it with hidden `<Input>` so your set of rules will still applied. The quill component is uncontrolled component and every time it change, it will also change the value of the hidden `<Input>` so when you submit or get the value of the form, the value of it is the value of quill component.

Also the warning you get `addRange(): the given range isn't in the document` was not visible on the codesandbox. You may look into [this](https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/1940#issuecomment-379536850) about that.