# useState variable not changing on keystroke

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a login form made from a map of a FormInput component.

I have now created separate FormComponents depending on the question type as defined by a prop.

However, since making this change my 'credentials' state is not updating on a user keystroke.

I would like the CREDENTIALS state to be updated on keystroke. However, this is not happening currently.

LoginForm

```
import React from 'react';
import FormInput from '../../components/Form Input/FormInput';
import { loginInputs } from '../../formSource/formSourceData';
import './Login.scss';
import { useState, useContext } from 'react';
import { useNavigate, Link, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useToastContext } from '../../context/toastContext';
import useFetch from '../../Hooks/UseFetch';
import { AuthContext } from '../../context/AuthContext'
import axios from 'axios'


const Login = () => {

  const [credentials, setCredentials] = useState({
    email: undefined,
    password: undefined,
  });

  const { user, loading, error, dispatch} = useContext(AuthContext)

  const { toastDispatch } = useToastContext();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { state } = useLocation()

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.name)
    setCredentials({ ...credentials, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    console.log(credentials)
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    dispatch({type: "LOGIN_START"})
    try{
      const res = await axios.post("/api/auth/login", credentials)
      dispatch({type:"LOGIN_SUCCESS", payload: res.data})
      navigate(state?.path || '/auth/teacher/dashboard');
    } catch(err) {
      dispatch({type: "LOGIN_FAILURE", payload: err.response.data})
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="formWrapper">
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <form className="loginForm" >
          {loginInputs.map((input) => (
            <FormInput
              key={input.id}
              {...input}
              handleChange={handleChange}
            />
          ))}
          <button type="submit" className="loginButton" onClick={handleSubmit}>
            Login
          </button>
        </form>
        <p className="forgotPassword">
          <Link to="/forgot-password">Forgot Password</Link>
        </p>
        <p className="accountText">
          Not signed up? <Link to="/register">Register</Link>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

FormInputComponent

```
import { InputRounded } from '@mui/icons-material';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './formInput.scss';

const FormInput = (props) => {
  const { label, type, errorMessage, handleChange, id, value, ...inputProps } =
    props;

  const [focused, setFocused] = useState(false);
  const [passwordShown, setPasswordShown] = useState(false);

  const handleFocus = (e) => {
    setFocused(true);
  };

  const togglePassword = () => {
    setPasswordShown(!passwordShown);
  };

  const Dropdown = () => {
    return (
      <select
        className="formElementInput"
        value={value}
        name={inputProps.name}
        onChange={handleChange}
      >
        <option className="default" selected disabled>
          {inputProps.placeholder}
        </option>
        {inputProps.options.map((option) => (
          <option className="option" value={option}>
            {option}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
    );
  };

  const Input = () => {
    return (
      <div className="formGroup">
        <input
          className="formElementInput"
          value={value}
          name={props.name}
          placeholder={props.placeholder}
          type={passwordShown ? 'text' : type}
          onChange={props.handleChange}
          onBlur={handleFocus}
          focused={focused.toString()}
          onFocus={() =>
            inputProps.name === 'confirmPassword' && setFocused(true)
          }
        />
        <span className="icon" onClick={togglePassword}>
          {passwordShown ? inputProps.icon : inputProps.opposite}
        </span>
      </div>
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="formElement">
      <label className="formElementLabel">{label}</label>
      {type === 'dropdown' ? (
        <Dropdown />
      ) : (
        <Input/>
      )}

      <span className="errorMessage">{errorMessage}</span>
    </div>
  );
};

export default FormInput;
```

LOGIN INPUT CODE

```
export const loginInputs = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "email",
        type: "email",
        placeholder: "Email",
        label: "Email",
        errorMessage: "Enter a valid email address",
        required: true

    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "password",
        type: "password",
        placeholder: "Password",
        label: "Password",
        errorMessage: "A password should be more than 8 characters.",
        required: true,
        icon: <Visibility/>,
        opposite: <VisibilityOff/>

    }
]
```

This is the original working code prior to separating.

```
import { InputRounded } from '@mui/icons-material';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './formInput.scss';

const FormInput = (props) => {
  const { label, type, errorMessage, handleChange, id, value, ...inputProps } =
    props;

  const [focused, setFocused] = useState(false);
  const [passwordShown, setPasswordShown] = useState(false);

  const handleFocus = (e) => {
    setFocused(true);
  };

  const togglePassword = () => {
    setPasswordShown(!passwordShown);
  };

  const Dropdown = () => {
    return (
      <select
        className="formElementInput"
        value={value}
        name={inputProps.name}
        onChange={handleChange}
      >
        <option className="default" selected disabled>
          {inputProps.placeholder}
        </option>
        {inputProps.options.map((option) => (
          <option className="option" value={option}>
            {option}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
    );
  };

  const Input = () => {
    return (
      <div className="formGroup">
        <input
          className="formElementInput"
          value={value}
          name={props.name}
          placeholder={props.placeholder}
          type={passwordShown ? 'text' : type}
          onChange={props.handleChange}
          onBlur={handleFocus}
          focused={focused.toString()}
          onFocus={() =>
            inputProps.name === 'confirmPassword' && setFocused(true)
          }
        />
        <span className="icon" onClick={togglePassword}>
          {passwordShown ? inputProps.icon : inputProps.opposite}
        </span>
      </div>
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="formElement">
      <label className="formElementLabel">{label}</label>
      {type === 'dropdown' ? (

        <select
          className="formElementInput"
          value={value}
          name={inputProps.name}
          onChange={handleChange}
        >
          <option className="default" selected disabled>
            {inputProps.placeholder}
          </option>
          {inputProps.options.map((option) => (
            <option className="option" value={option} >
              {option}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
      ) : (
        <div className="formGroup">
          <input
            className="formElementInput"
            value={value}
            name={inputProps.name}
            placeholder={inputProps.placeholder}
            type={passwordShown ? "text" : type}
            onChange={handleChange}
            onBlur={handleFocus}
            focused={focused.toString()}
            onFocus={() =>
              inputProps.name === 'confirmPassword' && setFocused(true)
            }
          />
          <span className="icon" onClick={togglePassword}>
              {passwordShown ? inputProps.icon : inputProps.opposite}
          </span> 
          </div>
      )}

      <span className="errorMessage">{errorMessage}</span>
    </div>
  );
};

export default FormInput;
```

[image: Edit thirsty-feather-9fwwwy]

Here is a link to the code sandbox which exhibits the same behaviour I have explained above.

https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-feather-9fwwwy?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Can you also show code for `loginInputs` ?

Comment: How do you know credentials state is not updating ? Put `console.log(credentials)` out side of `handleChange` (before `handleSubmit`); then you will see

Comment: @ShivamJha, thank you. When I console.log, Credentials prints. However, it does not update to the user input.

Comment: Try `setCredentials(prev => ({ ...prev, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }));`

Comment: @ShivamJha Again thank you for your efforts here. Unfortunately, this doesn't solve the issue. However, could you perhaps explain what you were trying to do. Perhaps it could help me.

Comment: I was thinking this was probably due to a race condition. Can you create a code sandbox example for this issue ? It will be helpful. https://codesandbox.io/s/react-new

Comment: @ShivamJha, thank you. I have created a code sandbox which exhibits the same behaviour. This can be found in the post above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that your `<Input />` component inside `FormComponent.jsx` is controlled.. so it looks for the `value` attribute in rendered input field, but could not find any:

```
return (
      <div className="formGroup">
        <input
          className="formElementInput"
          name={props.name}
          value={props.value}
          placeholder={props.placeholder}
          type={passwordShown ? "text" : props.type}
          onChange={props.handleChange}
          onBlur={handleFocus}
          focused={focused.toString()}
          onFocus={() => props.name === "confirmPassword" && setFocused(true)}
        />
        // ...
```

Because.. there is not any:

```
// Notice no value `key` on any of these objects:
export const loginInputs = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "email",
    type: "email",
    placeholder: "Email",
    label: "Email",
    errorMessage: "Enter a valid email address",
    required: true
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "password",
    type: "password",
    placeholder: "Password",
    label: "Password",
    errorMessage: "A password should be more than 8 characters.",
    required: true,
    icon: "Icon",
    opposite: "Icon2"
  }
];
```

to fix that, you can provide a value attribute, depending upon your `credentials` state:

```
{loginInputs.map((input) => (
  <FormInput
    key={input.id}
    value={credentials[input.name] ?? ""} // provide value prop
    {...input}
    handleChange={handleChange}
  />
))}
```

Bonus: I noticed that the input lost it's focus every time you typed there(maybe this was not the problem in your code, just in Sandbox you provided).

This was because you declared `<Input />` inside the `<FormInput />` so everytime it changed, it basically created that `<Input />` component from scratch. These are many ways to do it, but the easiest is to just use it inline in ternary:

```
{props.type === "dropdown" ? (
        <Dropdown /> // Also do the same for `Dropdown` if  face the similar isssue
      ) : (
        // used inline
        <div className="formGroup">
          <input
            className="formElementInput"
            name={props.name}
            value={props.value}
            placeholder={props.placeholder}
            type={passwordShown ? "text" : props.type}
            onChange={props.handleChange}
            onBlur={handleFocus}
            focused={focused.toString()}
            onFocus={() => props.name === "confirmPassword" && setFocused(true)}
          />
          <span className="icon" onClick={togglePassword}>
            {passwordShown ? props.icon : props.opposite}
          </span>
        </div>
      )}
```

Here's the link to updated Sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-poitras-84z4do?file=/Login.jsx:943-995

Comment: you fixed it. However, it was your bonus that fixed it for me. I didn't see that it was because the focus was lost. Could you perhaps elaborate on why this occured or where I could read up more on this? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Glad to hear that. You can find more about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42573017/in-react-es6-why-does-the-input-field-lose-focus-after-typing-a-character