# Formik causing MUI number textfield to lose focus

Tags: forms, material-ui, formik

When I bind formik values to a textfield with type 'number' any attempt to manually type a number e.g. 14 in the text field allows you to enter a single number e.g. 1 before it then loses focus on the input and to add the next digit (4) you have to click on the input to refocus it once more.

When I remove value={formik.values.newValue} and onChange={formik.handleChange} you can once again type freely in the input. This would suggest that the behaviour seen has something to do with the binding between or influence of formik on the textfield.

The field is set to have a default, minimum and maximum value which is retrieved from a config file that returns the fields numerical values in the following format:

```
const Data: Data = {
    name: "Test Name",
    dataType: DataType.Number,
    default: 50,
    lowerBoundary: 0,
    upperBoundary: 100
  };
```

I've created a [code sandbox demonstrating my implementation](https://codesandbox.io/s/number-field-kv4cnz?file=/Form.tsx:269-410) but I'd like to resolve the above issue with the field losing focus so that a user can then freely type a full number in one go.

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47660885/13405106) will help, try putting whats inside `NumberInputComponent` in `NumberForm` instead. [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/number-field-forked-q47ny8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above comment answered this question and linked answer helps provide details as to why. Ultimately, I had to remove the method:

```
const NumberInputComponent: React.FC<NumberInputComponentProps> = ({
    label,
    Data,
    min,
    max,
    default: defaultValue
  }) => (
    <FormControl fullWidth>
      <TextField
        id="newValue"
        name="newValue"
        label={label}
        type="number"
        value={formik.values.newValue}
        onChange={formik.handleChange}
        inputProps={{
          min: { min },
          max: { max }
        }}
        error={
          Number(formik.values.newValue) < Number(min) ||
          Number(formik.values.newValue) > Number(max)
        }
        helperText={
          Number(formik.values.newValue) < Number(min)
            ? `Below minimum: ${min}`
            : Number(formik.values.newValue) > Number(max)
            ? `Above maximum: ${max}`
            : ""
        }
      />
      <FormHelperText>
        <p>
          <b>Minimum</b> {min} <b>Maximum</b> {max}{" "}
        </p>
        <p>
          <b>Default</b> {defaultValue}{" "}
        </p>
      </FormHelperText>
    </FormControl>
  );
```

And take the textfield and place this inside my form rather than generating it from a method to stop it from returning a new field every time a user typed and thus lose the focus on the field.

Comment: Stack Overflow [recommends](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to *quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Links to other websites should always be helpful, but avoid making it necessary to click on them*. Please update your question and answer by posting relevant code from codesandbox.io and summarizing explanations referenced from links and comments with attributions where possible.