# React - Input loses focus after typing 1 char in dynamic form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, dynamic-forms, react-state-management

I'm trying to create a dynamic form, in this form users can add as many books as they want, and each book has a name and an link.

I already have a button *Add a Book* and fields are added correctly in my form, but when I type in any one of these fields my input loses the focus

I'm saving `books []` inside of my component state, and to update it I have an `onChange={(e) => this.handleDynamicChange(e, 'fieldName', index)}` in my input.

*handleDynamicChange*

```
handleDynamicChange = (event, name, index) => {
    const { value } = event.target;

    let { books } = this.state;
    books[index][name] = value;
    this.setState({ books });
}
```

My input for book link (using material ui):

```
<TextField
    id={`edit-profile-book-link-${index}`}
    label='Link'
    value={book.link}
    onChange={(e) => this.handleDynamicChange(e, 'link', index)}
/>
```

I guess it's because I'm updating the entire books array, so react is re-rendering all books fields, but I couldn't find a way to update only one book using `setState()`, so, do you know how to handle these updates inside of a dynamic form ?

I already saw that question but didn't help:
[React.js - input losing focus when rerendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22573494/react-js-input-losing-focus-when-rerendering)

I have been checking this tutorial:
[building a dynamic controlled form](https://itnext.io/building-a-dynamic-controlled-form-in-react-together-794a44ee552c)

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help, but generally you should have a unique `key` prop on the top level component inside a loop. If your `TextField` is inside a loop, add something like `key={i}`

Comment: The problem is not evident from the code that you've posted, it seems to work just fine, here is an example https://codesandbox.io/embed/material-demo-iqdmg

Comment: Thanks, the key solved my problem, I was already adding a random key, but if the key changes, the input loses the focus. using index it's ok.

Answer (score 1):

```
    let { books } = this.state;
    books[index][name] = value;
```

Here you are **mutating** the state, you shouldn't be manipulating the state directly. The recommend way of doing this is to use `the spread operator`.

```
this.setState({ books: [...this.state.books,
                   this.state.books[index]: {...this.state.book[index], this.state.books[index][name]: value}
                ] })
```

Comment: `books` is an array, and the recommended way is not using *the spread operator* is calling `setState` with a function that receives the previous state as an argument.

Comment: No, the shortest way is to use the spread operator. You can achive the same thing without it, but it is long. So the recommended way is to use the spread operator. @Titus

Comment: That still won't work, it should be something like this: `this.setState(prevState => ({books: prevState.books.map((book, i) => {if (i === index) {return {...book, [link]: value};} return book;})}))`

Comment: In this scenario you don't have to use the `prevState`. @Titus