# Updating & appending to React array state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a form where users create a coding problem. In the form, there is the option to add sample test cases via input and output text boxes. The user can click a button to add a new test case. Right now I have a state object that holds all of the form data, formObj, and within it is a sample_test_cases field which I want to hold an array of objects, like: [{ input: "", output: "" }].

The issue I am having is updating this array. I need to be able to concat a new object to it each time a test case is added. Then updating the state at that index when the text box is changed. I have tried creating a stateless array and updating it, then setting sample_test_cases to that array. This is not working, however.

Here is a sandbox with my code: https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-snowflake-n4bpl?file=/src/AddProblemForm.js

If anyone could give me tips that would really help. I'm not too familiar with Javascript or complex state management. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See snippet below (I'm having issues with saving the sandbox). A few issues that it addresses:

1. You also kept track of state using some local `arr` variable; updating that won't trigger a re-render, so you'll need to modify the `sample_test_cases` array inside your `formObj` state.
2. The textarea `value` should also be reflecting what is in your state. To make this more convenient, I've passed the test case into the `SampleTestCase` component as a prop, so it will react to state changes.
3. React state should be treated as immutable. So when the input text box is updated, you should set the state to a *new*  object with a *new* `sample_test_cases` array, which is constructed of the first i-1 test cases, a *new* ith test case with modified input, and the remaining test cases.
4. Move `SampleTestCase` outside of the `AddProblemForm` component. If you don't, you will find that whenever the input textarea is changed, you will lose keyboard focus. This is because the `SampleTestCase` component is being redefined *on each render*, which is triggered by a state change. (Similar problem: [React.js - input losing focus when rerendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22573494/react-js-input-losing-focus-when-rerendering))

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Form, Button, Col } from "react-bootstrap";
import { BsPlusSquare } from "react-icons/bs";

const SampleTestCase = ({ testCase, updateInput }) => {
  return (
    <Form.Row>
      <Col>
        <Form.Group controlId="input">
          <Form.Label>Sample Input</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            required
            as="textarea"
            rows={2}
            onChange={updateInput}
            value={testCase.input}
          />
        </Form.Group>
      </Col>
      <Col>
        <Form.Group controlId="output">
          <Form.Label>Sample Output</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            required
            as="textarea"
            rows={2}
            // onChange={(event) =>
            //   setFormObj({
            //     ...formObj,
            //     sample_test_cases: {
            //       ...formObj.sample_test_cases,
            //       output: event.target.value
            //     }
            //   })
            // }
          />
        </Form.Group>
      </Col>
    </Form.Row>
  );
};

const AddProblemForm = () => {
  const [formObj, setFormObj] = useState({
    sample_test_cases: [{ input: "", output: "" }]
    // other state obj info
  });

  const AddSampleTestCase = () => {
    // make new instance!
    const newTestCase = { input: "", output: "" };
    setFormObj({
      ...formObj,
      sample_test_cases: [...formObj.sample_test_cases, newTestCase]
    });
  };

  console.log(formObj);

  const updateInputFor = (i) => (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const { sample_test_cases } = formObj;
    const testCase = sample_test_cases[i];
    testCase.input = event.target.value;

    setFormObj({
      ...formObj,
      sample_test_cases: [
        ...sample_test_cases.slice(0, i),
        testCase,
        ...sample_test_cases.slice(i + 1)
      ]
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      Problem Form
      <Form>
        <h5 style={{ paddingTop: "1rem" }}>Sample Test Cases</h5>
        {formObj.sample_test_cases.map((testCase, i) => (
          <React.Fragment key={i}>
            <SampleTestCase
              key={i}
              testCase={testCase}
              updateInput={updateInputFor(i)}
            />
            <hr />
          </React.Fragment>
        ))}
        <Button onClick={AddSampleTestCase}>
          <div>Add Sample Test Case</div>
        </Button>
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AddProblemForm;
```

Comment: Sandbox works now: https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-shannon-fto3p?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark&file=/src/AddProblemForm.js

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use useReducer hook in cases your state is complicated.

[hooks API](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html)

> useReducer is usually preferable to useState when you have complex
> state logic that involves multiple sub-values or when the next state
> depends on the previous one.

**AddProblemForm.js**:

```
import React, { useReducer } from "react";
import { Form, Button, Col } from "react-bootstrap";
import { BsPlusSquare } from "react-icons/bs";
import SampleTestCase from "./SampleTestCase";

const initialState = {
  sample_test_cases: [],
  counter: 0
  // other state obj info
};
function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "addSampleTestCase": {
      const { data } = action;
      return {
        ...state,
        sample_test_cases: [...state.sample_test_cases, data],
        counter: state.counter + 1
      };
    }
    case "updateTest": {
      const { index, value } = action;
      return {
        ...state,
        sample_test_cases: state.sample_test_cases.map((item, i) => {
          if (i === index) {
            return value;
          } else {
            return item;
          }
        })
      };
    }

    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
}

const AddProblemForm = () => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  const AddSampleTestCase = () => {
    dispatch({ type: "addSampleTestCase", data: { input: "", output: "" } });
  };

  /* console.log(state); */

  return (
    <div>
      Problem Form
      <Form>
        <h5 style={{ paddingTop: "1rem" }}>Sample Test Cases</h5>
        {state.sample_test_cases.map((sample_test_case, i) => (
          <div key={i}>
            <SampleTestCase
              sample_test_case={sample_test_case}
              updateValue={(value) =>
                dispatch({ type: "updateTest", index: i, value })
              }
            />
            <hr />
          </div>
        ))}
        <Button onClick={AddSampleTestCase}>
          <div>Add Sample Test Case</div>
        </Button>
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AddProblemForm;
```

**SampleTestCase.js**:

```
import React from "react";
import { Form, Button, Col } from "react-bootstrap";

const SampleTestCase = ({ sample_test_case, updateValue }) => {
  return (
    <Form.Row>
      <Col>
        <Form.Group controlId="input">
          <Form.Label>Sample Input</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            required
            as="textarea"
            rows={2}
            value={sample_test_case.input}
            onChange={(event) => updateValue(event.target.value)}
          />
        </Form.Group>
      </Col>
      <Col>
        <Form.Group controlId="output">
          <Form.Label>Sample Output</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            required
            as="textarea"
            rows={2}
            value={sample_test_case.output}
            onChange={(event) => updateValue(event.target.value)}
          />
        </Form.Group>
      </Col>
    </Form.Row>
  );
};
export default SampleTestCase;
```